# Changing scrollview's position in Android

Tags: android, position

I'm writing an Android application that has a scrollview which contains a linearlayout:

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_gravity=top"
        android:layout_marginTop="240dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dip">

         <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/centerlayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="120dip">
```

As you see, scrollview's margin top is "240dip" . I want to be able to change it in my Java code. I tried this:

```
ScrollView scrollView=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.ScrollView01);
LayoutParams  params=scrollView.getLayoutParams();
```

But I can't do this: params.top=100; Would you please help me how I can do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean that you "can't do this". You would have to do `params.top=100;` and then `scrollView.setLayoutParams(params);`.

But you could change it to:

```
ScrollView scrollView=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.ScrollView01);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(scrollView.getLayoutParams());
params.topMargin = 100;
scrollView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
```

without the line you will have problems.